# Reputation graph in Chrome

Tags: bug

I just noticed what seems to be a small bug; hopefully this question is not a duplicate.  When I go to my user page, under "reputation" there is a timeline which I should be able to manipulate by dragging the mouse across it.  In Safari, this feature works perfectly; in Chrome it seems not to work at all.  How does one fix this?

Comment: This question already has an answer at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105061/select-an-area-in-rep-graph-not-working-on-chrome

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen:  Thanks!  Setting the zoom to 100% seems to fix it (though of course it should work in any zoom)...